# Node - Angular Passing POST data from Server to Angular client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a Node.js server with Angular on the client side. I'd like the following to happen.

User posts a large JSON to `/postjson`. The large JSON object is used in the controller to render some data visualization. I don't want to store the JSON in a database, it should disappear when the window closes. How do I pass this data to the controller?

A potential solution is to use a route `/api/postjson` and receive the JSON server side. But I don't want to store it. How do I then pass this object to the controller/service/provider whatever is required?

Comment: your question is a bit unfocused.  passing data from the client to the server doesn't imply that the server would store it anywhere....

Comment: Does your server do any transformation to data? Can you use FileAPI to load data on client w/o touching server at all?